# How do I get the form labels so they are in-line and right justified, against the form elements

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox, alignment

For the life of me I can't get my labels to be in-lin and right justified against form elements, rather I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtYEr.png)

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.feedback_right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
}

/* Contact Form Styling */

form#contact_form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

form#contact_form p {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
}

form#contact_form p > label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 2px;
    text-align: right;
}


form#contact_form p > input {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="feedback_right">
        <form id="contact_form">
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_name">Full Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_email">Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="Email">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_number">Mobile Number:</label>
                    <input type="tel" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="victoria">Victoria</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="victoria" name="victoria">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="queensland">Queensland</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="queensland" name="queensland">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="new_south_wales">New South Wales</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="new_south_wales" name="new_south_wales">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="act">Australian Capital Territory</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="act" name="act">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="tasmania">Tasmania</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="tasmania" name="tasmania">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="south_australia">South Australia</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="south_australia" name="south_australia">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="western_australia">Western Australia</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="western_australia" name="western_australia">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="northern_territory">Northern Territory</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="northern_territory" name="northern_territory">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="contact_message" name="contact_message" placeholder="Message"></textarea> 
                </p>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
          </div>
    </section>
```

I want the submit button to stay exactly where it is, I just need some assistance in troubleshooting and getting the labels right align against the input elements that are all nicely aligned.

My desired outcome would be something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqfiE.png) - just without that vertical divider line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be really hard to do, if you are not just a backend dev with little knowledge of css. Just float them right!!!, and then play around with the max-width of the whole form as you like.

I have shown #3 method to right justify the label items, there are plenty of ways to do that though.

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.feedback_right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
}

/* Contact Form Styling */

form#contact_form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

form#contact_form p {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
}

form#contact_form p > label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 2px;
    text-align: right;
}


form#contact_form p > input {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/*Why not just float them right??*/ 

label {
  float: right;
}

label[for="contact_message"] {
  float: none;
}

input {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 52px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="feedback_right">
        <form id="contact_form">
                <p>
                    
                    <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
                    <label for="contact_name">Full Name:</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                   
                    <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="Email">
                     <label for="contact_email">Email Address:</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                   
                    <input type="tel" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                     <label for="contact_number">Mobile Number:</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    
                    <input type="radio" id="victoria" name="victoria">
                    <label for="victoria">Victoria</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    
                    <input type="radio" id="queensland" name="queensland">
                    <label for="queensland">Queensland</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    
                    <input type="radio" id="new_south_wales" name="new_south_wales">
                    <label for="new_south_wales">New South Wales</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                   
                    <input type="radio" id="act" name="act">
                     <label for="act">Australian Capital Territory</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    
                    <input type="radio" id="tasmania" name="tasmania">
                    <label for="tasmania">Tasmania</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    
                    <input type="radio" id="south_australia" name="south_australia">
                    <label for="south_australia">South Australia</label>
                </p>
               
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="contact_message" name="contact_message" placeholder="Message"></textarea> 
                </p>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
          </div>
    </section>
```

Flexbox approach:

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.feedback_right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
}

/* Contact Form Styling */

form#contact_form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

form#contact_form p {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
}

form#contact_form p > label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 2px;
    text-align: right;
}


form#contact_form p > input {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/*changes*/  

form#contact_form p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

form#contact_form p > label {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="feedback_right">
        <form id="contact_form">
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_name">Full Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_email">Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="Email">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_number">Mobile Number:</label>
                    <input type="tel" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="victoria">Victoria</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="victoria" name="victoria">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="queensland">Queensland</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="queensland" name="queensland">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="new_south_wales">New South Wales</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="new_south_wales" name="new_south_wales">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="act">Australian Capital Territory</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="act" name="act">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="tasmania">Tasmania</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="tasmania" name="tasmania">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="south_australia">South Australia</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="south_australia" name="south_australia">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="western_australia">Western Australia</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="western_australia" name="western_australia">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="northern_territory">Northern Territory</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="northern_territory" name="northern_territory">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="contact_message" name="contact_message" placeholder="Message"></textarea> 
                </p>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
          </div>
    </section>
```

You can eliminate the last textarea label from flex positioning yourself.

Comment: @BeauBarbera That's alright, I've lived in Hobart as well by the way, got no idea how Tafe teaches web technologies there, but you should lean some basic html and css before trying to make things/webpages. w3school, mdn etc. Float is the most fundamental concept for layout.

Comment: Thank you - apologies if it's easy to you. I am only just new to it, studying it at tafe. I'd need to look at an alternative, the form labels need to in-line and right justified against the form elements, as per the original post question. 

Thanks @user31782 - I do know basic html, however we were told to avoid floats for this assessment. We've had to build a complete website for this assessment, so far everything is ready to submit aside from this pages.

Comment: Then, #1 it would be best to keep them in a different column altogether and give `text-align: right` -- gonna have to consider if clikcing on label needs to trigger focus to the respective input. #2 An easier way is to give fixed width to all labels and use `text-align: right`.  #3 Or you can float:right the labels as well and give margin-left to the inputs. Let me show you #3

Comment: Thank you - I am trying to essentially centre the form within a flexbox that already has a defined position on the page. Within this flexbox I need to align the form with the labels justified and right aligned against the input elements :-)

Comment: @BeauBarbera Check my edit.  With flexbox, it is gonna be similar to my #2 method, give either `width` or `flex-basis` to the labels, and then apply text-align right on them. #4 another even quicker way: https://jsfiddle.net/dw6Lmcv1/   just apply fixed width to labels and give em padding-right. P.S Was just thinkgin of `direction` writing mode stuff -- maybe could affect right justifying the text, without explicit width.

Comment: Just realized you have already got `display: flex` on the `p`, all you need is `flex-grow: 1` on the labels with some padding-right.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help - I will give it a finalise now and see how it goes :-)